# Unable to use pipenv to install: ImportError: cannot import name 'InstallRequirement' from 'pip_shims.shims'

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv, pipenv-install

Since a few hours I had issues with installing dependencies via pipenv. I decided to recreate my environment again and start from scratch, using a different python version (3.8.9). I'm now unable to even install any packages at all, and retrieve the following traceback:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip_shims.shims import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'InstallRequirement' from 'pip_shims.shims' (unknown location)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, it seems an extended command is required, like so:

```
python3 -m pipenv install xyz
```

Before I was justing using

```
pipenv install xyz
```

Comment: This just runs a different version of pipenv (and/or uses a different version of Python). It seems that whatever version of pipenv you get when running `python3 -m pipenv` has a fix for this error, whereas the version you get when running just `pipenv` doesn't. It would have been useful if you could have included in the answer which versions those were, although I suppose it's probably impossible to know almost two years later... but maybe if someone else encounters this error they can fill in details.